# How to select the first null column in a row in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am a MySQL newbie.
Consider this is how a row looks on a table in my database

```
id q1 q2 q3 q4 q5
```

and the values for each of these columns is as follows

```
01 abc null null null
```

which means that the 3rd column (q2) is null

I would like to select this null column using MySQL. In this example, I know that q3 is null, however, when this code is running on my website, I will have to find out the null column and will have to insert values into that. Can anyone help me here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select q3 from mytable` ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @Techuire : `select q2 from table_name where q2 IS NULL`

Comment: I suppose you actually mean that you do not want to select the column contents (which in this scenario is known upfront anyway), but you want to get the _name_ of the column returned? Then you will have to use control flow functions to write a logic that accomplishes that, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html (That is assuming you are okay with putting the column names into the statement statically. If you wanted this for tables of unknown structure, this would get a lot more complex.)

Comment: Here is what i want. There are 20 columns in this table. I will be updating 1 field at a time in 1 row. I will have to see which field is currently null, and the will update that field.

Answer (score 0):

select * from mytable where column = null limit 1

Comment: Are you sure about your query?

Comment: yes, you can find all where data null in your table and if you want use order by id, asc for the first data and limit 1 to get first value

Comment: Asker wants the first column which value is null. In your query, it is not satisfied.

Comment: The problem is that I would not know which is the first column that will be null. It would be like I would go into the database everytime, see which is the first null value and will insert data into that.